# Django Request Session on anonymous users

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following problem:

I'm using the Django Rest framework with anonymous users (i don't have users in my application) and in my views file when i try to modify the `request.session` variable, the value is not persistent in all views. I have two different class based views:

```
def post(self, request):
  ...
  request.session["instances"] = serializer.data 
  request.session.modified = True
  ...
  return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

def get(self, request, page):
  ...
  print request.session["instances"]
  ...
  return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

On the second view i get a key error, basically the key "instances" doesn't exist. This is my settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

############
# SESSIONS #
############

# Cache to store session data if using the cache session backend.
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'
# Cookie name. This can be whatever you want.
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
# Age of cookie, in seconds (default: 2 weeks).
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 2
# A string like ".example.com", or None for standard domain cookie.
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
# Whether the session cookie should be secure (https:// only).
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
# The path of the session cookie.
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
# Whether to use the non-RFC standard httpOnly flag (IE, FF3+, others)
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# Whether a user's session cookie expires when the Web browser is closed.
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
# The module to store session data
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
# Directory to store session files if using the file session module. If None,
# the backend will use a sensible default.
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None
# class to serialize session data
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'

#########
# CACHE #
#########

# The cache backends to use.
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = ''
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
```

I haven't been able to store data on `request.session` successfully, i tried checking if the session has a `session_key` but it prints `None`, so i created a session on the first view with `session_id = request.session._get_or_create_session_key()` but still on the second view it doesn't exist anymore (`session_key` is `None`). Anybody here had this problem before?

Comment: try to set SESSION_ENGINE to 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'

Comment: What is your `CACHES` configuration in Django `settings.py`? Are you by any chance using the `DummyCache` backend?

Comment: @rtindru I'm using the default that's in the Django global settings:
`'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'`

Comment: @JibinMathews Tried but it didn't work, i still get a KeyError when i try to print `request.session["instances"]`

Comment: Can you add your `CACHES` configuration to the question. Hard to debug further without understanding how your cache is configured.

Comment: @rtindru Alright, I added them to the question, i also added the session configuration as well.

Comment: Solved it by adding `request.session.save()` (session_key had a value after saving the session), after this i used the session_key to query the database `session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)` on the other view and was able to retrieve the instances.